# Issue in loading http://www.google.com url in iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I was using the following code for checking the internet connection in my first iOS app (almost 3 years ago).

```objc
NSError *err = nil;
NSStringEncoding encoding;

NSString * connectionstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] usedEncoding:&encoding error:&err];

if(connectionstring.length ==0)
{
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Occured" message:@"No Internet Connection." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
else
{
    // loading another screen
}
```

The problem is in India and US it is going into the **else condition** but in **Belgium** it is going into the **if condition** and throwing the error. So are there any restrictions for Google in Belgium?

If it is tagged incorrectly please guide me. In my current versions solved this issue by using Rechability classes to check this . Just I wanted to know about it . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, look at the encoding.

You can log the encoding right after the connectionstring is created by inserting

```
NSLog(@"encoding: %@", [NSString localizedNameOfStringEncoding:encoding]);
```

into your code.

For further debugging, you could try loading the url into an NSData object first, then inspect the data and finally create a NSString from the data.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution: To check internet connection Use Reachability class provided by apple.
Download Apple Sample [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Reachability.zip), add Reachability class to your project.

```
- (BOOL)isConnected
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return !(networkStatus == NotReachable);
}
```

Comment: Thanks guru. I have used the Rechability classes in my current versions. Just I wanted to know about it .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using google.com use any local client server test url for internet checking it will also be very fast responsive comparatively of any other way of internet validation.